# MONO mscorlib.dll customize

Tags: mono, moonlight, mscorlib

I am embedding mono in my framework. For the security purpose I want to customize mscorlib.dll. I want to inject securityattributes in my mscorlib.dll. Is it possible to remove some feature or inject securityattributes using monolinker in mscorlib.dll

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's how Moonlight did it (injection). This wiki [page](http://www.mono-project.com/CoreClrHowTo) will tell you (or link to) everything about it.

If it's not there then you'll have to read the [Makefile, scripts](https://github.com/mono/moon) and [README](https://github.com/mono/moon/blob/master/class/SecurityAttributes/README) instructions used to build Moonlight.